# react-redux-v6: withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to call a function from a connected component using `ref`, so I used before from `withRef: true` in connected component:

```js
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {withRef: true}
)(InviteReceiverForm)
```

and in the presentational component:

```js
<ExampleComponent 
  ref={ cmp => { if(cmp) { this.individualSenderFormRef = cmp.getWrappedInstance() }} />
```

But after I updated to `react-redux v6`, I got this error:

`withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component`

How can I use ref in `react-redux v6`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to replace `withRef` with `forwardRef` [as per the release notes](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0):

> The `withRef` option to connect has been replaced with `forwardRef`. If `{forwardRef : true}` has been passed to `connect`, adding a ref to the connected wrapper component will actually return the instance of the wrapped component.

So in your case:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {forwardRef: true}
)(InviteReceiverForm)
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
    null,
    {
      forwardRef: true
    }
  )
)(ComponentName);
```